# How to make property types in interface depend on each other?

Tags: typescript

I can't seem to figure out a dynamic way to have `dataItem` always be the same type as the value of the `field` property.
In the following example `dataItem` is always `string | Date | number` instead of being the specific one depending on what the `field` property is.

```
interface TableColumn<D> {
  field: keyof D
  renderCell: (dataItem: D[keyof D]) => ReactNode
}

interface Data {
  foo: string
  bar: Date
  fiz: number
}

const data: Data = {
  foo: "my foo",
  bar: new Date(),
  fiz: 32
}

const tableColumn: TableColumn<Data> = {
  field: "foo",
  renderCell: (dataItem) => dataItem // here dataItem should be string only
}

const tableColumn1: TableColumn<Data> = {
  field: "bar",
  renderCell: (dataItem) => dataItem // here dataItem should be Date only
}

const tableColumn2: TableColumn<Data> = {
  field: "fiz",
  renderCell: (dataItem) => dataItem // here dataItem should be number only
}
```

Comment: You can't do it with an interface, but you could make `TableColumn<D>` a union type that works this way.  See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mp8KMm).  Does that meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes that works perfectly! thank you!
Please write up an answer with explanation because I don't really understand how it works. what does the `-?` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interface wouldn't work this way; you could possibly make it more [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) like `TableColumn<D, K>` where `K` is a particular key type in `keyof D`, but then you'd have to specify `K` everywhere.

Instead I would make `TableColumn<D>` a *distributive object type* as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) that evaluates to a  [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the individual types corresponding to each `K` in `keyof T`.  The distributive object type is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) which turns every property value `K` from `keyof D` into one holding the desired type corresponding to that property key, and which is then immediately [indexed into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with `keyof D`.  Like this:

```
type TableColumn<D> = { [K in keyof D]-?:
  {
    field: K,
    renderCell: (dataItem: D[K]) => ReactNode
  }
}[keyof D]
```

Here we generate the mapped type `{ [K in keyof D]-?: { field: K, renderCell: (dataItem: D[K]) => ReactNode }}`, which becomes for `Data` something like

```
{
  foo: { field: "foo"; renderCell: (dataItem: string) => ReactNode }
  bar: { field: "bar"; renderCell: (dataItem: Date) => ReactNode }
  fiz: { field: "fiz"; renderCell: (dataItem: number) => ReactNode }
}
```

Note that the [mapping modifier `-?`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) just makes sure that any optional properties in `D` become required in the mapped type, since we don't want any `undefined`s floating around here.

Then we index into this via `{...}[keyof D]`, which turns that mapped type into a union of its value types, ultimately producing:

```
type TCD = TableColumn<Data>
/* type TCD = {
    field: "foo";
    renderCell: (dataItem: string) => ReactNode;
} | {
    field: "bar";
    renderCell: (dataItem: Date) => ReactNode;
} | {
    field: "fiz";
    renderCell: (dataItem: number) => ReactNode;
} */
```

That's the union type you want; in fact, it's a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) where `field` is the discriminant property.  That lets the compiler infer the type of `renderCell` from the type of `field`, and thus gives you the desired [contextual typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) on `renderCell`'s unannotated callback parameter:

```
const tableColumn: TableColumn<Data> = {
  field: "foo",
  renderCell: (dataItem) => dataItem
  // (parameter) dataItem: string
}

const tableColumn1: TableColumn<Data> = {
  field: "bar",
  renderCell: (dataItem) => dataItem
  // (parameter) dataItem: Date
}

const tableColumn2: TableColumn<Data> = {
  field: "fiz",
  renderCell: (dataItem) => dataItem
  // (parameter) dataItem: number
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShCGBjYA5A9gE2gXigVwDsBrAtAdwIG4oB6GqAZwggFsH8CCJEIGH4ATiCgAzNAKjAAFtACOeXsACWaAgCg1oSFAAq8AEYAbCAGE0hvCwIAeACIA+KLgDeUANoBpKEoJQiEEDQRKFsAXQBaAH4ALjUoKGc4+NElCEMMaKgPABok+IEIAiwBEzTDTIAKDHhgeABJYFZM209QgEonRzgkVEwIJIBfNQG3f0DgsI0fRoERJGhbGvgEpLE0TIZgAR8AcyT9QWaa-viRJQAvTIJLfQgBYY1NcGgdE1snXQNjMwsrOyX7GoaAAqSTPXRvD6JZIpNIZKAAIjWCMoeSgBSKd1KhnKUCqSwaTUYW12HWwXQQyHQWFRAygAB8VjCznDMgiDgIUWiMcVsbj8bVCSwjo0yRSetSILSGUzkiz0myzucuTCeViypVqoLGsKoNcWLcBGLYJTejThlBgTQNIhVJsoFr4CLli5Vmh1oiWMJkbl4hyrhAyCFjhU2r6UpcoABmABMDzUtoI9tqRlM5ksBEyelTPwz-1qjldp1SCsRPqSapKGrxjqFxtrOqSdDxYEE8BYEBmHQbRM22wIeyGCbtwEkXzTvwIAEYs+Pc39FgWoasS-D2YIEeHK3zNQSdfW96wm-QKq2BO3O3du4fdYv+kPE8m5+mrDHZzmXzZF-BC7L5WulU3CtCl5asBXqfdOgdG9jxbNsOy7aDtSJfVDWGIA)